# Microwave Oven Transformer Calculations

Tags: transformer

I am designing a spot welder using a transformer from an old microwave and need to calculate the welding current that will be generated. I'm fairly certain that knowing the input voltage and power rating as well as the number of turns on the coils will allow me to do this, although I'm not entirely certain what's going on with my primary coil. It seems as though it has 16 'layers' and 8 turns on each layer. I'm not sure how this would effect my calculations, am I supposed to take the number of coils on my primary as 128?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WMzP.jpg

Comment: Is there any evidence anywhere that a regular microwave transformer rewound on the secondary with fewer turns will make a suitable spot-welder transformer?

Comment: @Andyaka --  Yes, here at [Make a Spot Welder for Cheap!!](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=vrlvqib94xQ), but he uses two transformers, and he doesn't ground the transformers, but I would ground them for safety.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you already wound the secondary. I think you probably know how many turns you have on the secondary or can count them pretty easily since there are just a few. So just measure the primary and secondary voltages while the secondary is open-circuited. Then you can calculate the primary turns using the basic voltage equation for transformers.

V1/N1 = V2/N2

Where V1 is the primary voltage, N1 is the number of turns on the primary, V2 is the secondary voltage, and N2 is the number of turns on the secondary. Just rearrange the equation to solve for N1.

Be careful not to get shocked by the primary side.